# Install the old version of the Ubuntu font

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family, 23.04

The Ubuntu font was redesigned to be thinner and, to my eyes, it is harder to read than the old one (yet the bold version looks extra chunky now?). This new thinner version is was introduced in Ubuntu 23.04.

I thought I might just download the older font and install it with ttf files, but can't since the new ones are installed. Removing the fonts-ubuntu package tries to take desktop package with it, so I couldn't do that.

How do I remove that font and replace it with the old version? Or have them side by side, that'd be just fine too as long as I could distinguish between the two. Yes, I could just change to another font, but I liked the old one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the old `fonts-ubuntu` package, for instance from here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/fonts-ubuntu/download

Then downgrade by simply installing that package locally.

- cd to the directory in which the downloaded package resides.
- Do:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i fonts-ubuntu_0.83-6ubuntu1_all.deb
  ```

Comment: That worked, but if I update apt tries to install the new version over it each time.

Comment: @FernMoss: Check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package).

Comment: Tell me if I should ask a new question or just comment ?
I'd like to *change* the interface/gnome-shell font, from _Ubuntu_ to _Ubuntu Condensed_ in 23.04 but seems like gnome-tweaks only applies to gnome-shell, not other parts of the interface nor app's.

Comment: @CoeurNoir: Please ask a new question about how to do that system wide.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson wise → https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468338/23-04-how-change-font-in-interface-gnome-shell-window-title-bar

Answer (score 1):

Check this article https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/04/restore-old-fonts-ubuntu-2304/ (I am not the author of it).

And hold for packages:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold fonts-ubuntu fonts-ubuntu-console
```

So you can skip Synaptic GUI part.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 provides the package fonts-ubuntu-classic for the old fonts, so there is no longer a need for workarounds. Source: The article linked above.

Comment: The fonts-ubuntu-classic package is indeed available in 23.10, making the replacement easy. The downside is that it totally replaces the new fonts (and removes the default fonts-ubuntu package), so you can't mix and match or compare the two.