# 23.04 : how change font in interface, gnome-shell, window title bar?

Tags: fonts, gnome-shell, interface, gnome-tweaks

might sound obvious, but I can't manage to change font in lunar lobster interface.

In previous versions I used to do it with *gnome-tweaks*, to change font from *Ubuntu* to *Ubuntu Condensed*.

Today it seems to only change *gnome-shell* font and nowhere else.

Is this expected or a « bug » in my installation ?

23.04 ↓
[image: as seen for the moment in a 23.04]

22.04 ↓
[image: what I can do on a 22.04 today, up-to-date]

Comment: I see the same thing when playing around with the font settings in Tweaks on my Ubuntu 22.04. Changing the font name does not take effect in e.g. Settings, but changing the font size does. Not sure if this is intended behavior, but the obvious first question to you is if you are sure it worked differently for you in previous Ubuntu versions?

Comment: It may be narrowed down to *condensed* type of font - but why ?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweaks/+bug/2019906

Comment: illustration from an actual 22.10 installation :

settings →  https://i.ibb.co/qybqpgs/2210-param-apparence.png

Comment: I wonder why I see the issue in 22.04 then. Maybe there is some stable release update which didn't happen in 22.10? As regards narrowed down, changing to an italic font style does not take effect in Settings either.

Comment: Nautilus from an actual 22.04  → https://i.ibb.co/qkbGRjk/nautilus-arbo-expand.png

Comment: I see your screenshot, but I can't change the Nautilus fonts that way on my 22.04. So I'm mostly confused ATM.

Comment: Mmm… the files for Ubuntu condensed fonts are named 'Ubuntu-C.ttf' but in 23.04 most of the fonts are symlinked to 'Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf' : https://i.ibb.co/hfYVGSk/ubuntu-fonts-2204-2304.png

Comment: True. When starting my tests on 22.04 I happened to have the new fonts-ubuntu version installed. So I downgraded to the old fonts-ubuntu version, but did not notice a difference with respect to the issue you brought up.

Comment: As a workaround,

install single file for Ubuntu Condensed Regular [ Ubuntu_Condensed_Regular.16.ttf ] as to be found in fonts.google.com through font-manager or manually,

into your $HOME/.local/share/fonts/ folder

rebuild font caches

and then beware to choose Ubuntu Condensed *Regular*
( and not any other Ubuntu Condensed *variant* )
in gnome-tweaks or dconf-editor.

This a not a fix, there is a problem with most condensed font variant installed by default in 23.04.